# JS переменная в php

Tags: php, javascript

Получаю js переменную `{{$route.url}}`. Как я могу ее вставить в код php?

```
$post = "{{$route.url}}"
```

Я использую framework7. Переменая передает текущий URL

Answer (score 2):

> Получаю js переменную `{{$route.url}}`. Как я могу ее вставить в код
>   php?

Ответ - никак. PHP работает на сервере, а JS на клиенте (в Вашем случае в мобильном приложении). Если нужно на основе этой переменной выполнить какие-либо действия на сервере, в "обычном" web приложении имело бы смысл использовать AJAX, который Framework 7 [тоже поддерживает](https://framework7.io/docs/request.html).